# Get image's URL as a token for use in Views' replacement pattern

Tags: views, media, tokens, uri

I need to get an image's full URL path as a token that I can use as a replacement pattern in Views.

I'm trying to have one thumbnail image link to a larger image.  I have the larger image excluded from view so I can use it as a token.  When I try to export the thumbnail image as a link using the larger image's token, the token is apparently the `<img>` tag instead of the path.

I think I can do this if I change the field type of the larger image to a File, but I want the benefits that come with the Image type (cropping, scaling, etc).

Answer (score 7):

I ended up using a module to create a custom formatter.  Image URL Formatter http://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter .  It created a new formatter option called "Image URL," and I can use that as a token.

Answer (score 4):

Old, but I think:

```
[node:IMAGEFIELD_TOKEN:file:url]
```

would do it

of in case of a multiple image field:

```
[node:IMAGEFIELD_TOKEN:IMAGEFIELD_IDX:file:url]
```

Where

- IMAGEFIELD_TOKEN is your image field token, like field-image, field-images, etc.
- IMAGEFIELD_IDX (for multiple fields) is your 0-based index. 0 for the first image, 1 for the second and so on.

Comment: Found it when doing this with media entity you need to replace underscores with hyphens: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/1334256#comment-10418391

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the token in this case is controlled by the formatter that renders the image. Perhaps the formatter has a setting to render the image as a direct link instead? I haven't tried doing this in Drupal 7, but with imagefield in D6 there was a direct link option.

If not, the best way to solve this is to add such a formatter.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip.  I ended up using a module to do this.  Image URL Formatter (http://drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter).  It created a new Formatter option called "Image URL," and I can use that as a token.

Comment: Glad you got it working. :) You should post that as an answer though, so you can accept it and the question becomes answered. Or it will remain in the "unanswered questions" queue forever.

Comment: Ha, gotcha.  I was just wondering if I did that right...

Comment: It certainly sounds right, and the answer that works for _you_ is by definition the one you should accept. I would just have thought no extra module was necessary.

Comment: From what I've read, I believe they took the image path formatter option away in Drupal 7?  The only option under "Formatter" that I saw was "Image."  I wasn't sure how to manually create a custom formatter, so I went with the module.