# Set lightbox effect for the link

Tags: 7, media

I have a gallery, created as a view:

http://hotelcentralpark.ro/gallery/2

Now the titles are links to the pages. And  images have lightbox effect.

[image]

I want the links to activate lightbox of the appropriate image. But there are no settings for that in the admin panel.

Here are the settings for the image field:

[image]

Settings for the header field in the control panel:

[image]

How can I set the link to act as lightbox?

Here is the image content type structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Views Use this code in "Rewrite the output of this field"

```
<a href="imagepath token" rel="lightbox">[title]</a>
```

You can also set the width and height of the popup window, see the read-me file in Lightbox2  module folder.

hope you will get idea from the above!!

Comment: I almost got it, but where should I get the image path token? `image-path` and `path` didn't work.

Comment: I updated my question, so you could see the content type fields, I am using.

Comment: I'm not sure, try this href="[field_gallery_fid]", Let me know

Comment: no, didn't work

Comment: Is there a place where I can at least look for this token?

Comment: @user4035 see this link for image url token  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32273/get-images-url-as-a-token-for-use-in-views-replacement-pattern